# Firewatch tower using geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

First time posting here.
I'm kinda new to geometry nodes but my goal was to make the tower from Firewatch using geometry nodes. looked like a solid repeatable structure and thought it would work using geometry nodes.
I've been trying for quite some time now but i can't find a right approach into making this tower, at least the base of it.
Does anyone have an idea, some suggestions, pointers, tutorials?
I've been able to make the horizontal rings of the base but they are instances and i need to vertex coordinates of each ring, so that i can make the diagonal and vertical beams. So i'm stuck there..[image]

Comment: Use Geometry Nodes if you want to create a procedural object with easily changeable properties: either because you want to have multiple different towers, or because you want to be able to adjust your tower as you work on your project (concept art seems a better alternative to geonodes though), or because you want to slightly modify the parameters on each frame = animate (unlikely in this case), or you want to produce an asset which users can adjust for their needs. I think that pretty much are all the reasons, so if none applies to you, maybe just use normal modeling?

Comment: in case you just wanna learn GN (sounds to me) watch tutorials of Erindale or Johnny Matthews to learn basics + more